# What other terms are there like yeísmo and betacismo?

Tags: pronunciación, terminología

I took a look at a bunch of questions here that were tagged *pronunciación*.  I learned the following terms:

yeísmo

betacismo

There is also *distinción-vs-seseo*.

1. In addition I came across *rotacismo*.  There are several questions about people's difficulty pronouncing the flapped R and the rolled R.  The [definition in Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotacismo) doesn't say anything about Spanish learners.  Would this term work just as well for Spanish learners' difficulties pronouncing the R in an authentic way?
2. Are there other terms like these?  For example, I'd like to find one that has to do with dropping the final S.

Answer (score 8):

*[Rotacismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotacismo)* (*rhotacism* in English) as a speech pathology (a [dyslalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyslalia)) is a well-known phenomenon in Spanish. It's not a dialectal feature like *yeísmo* or *distinción*. Its name is misleading, as it suggests sounds become rhotic, when in fact what happens is that rhotic sounds are mispronounced.

*[Sigmatismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmatismo)* (*sigmatism* in English) is phonetically equivalent to *ceceo* (substituting [s] for [θ]), but while *ceceo* is a dialectal feature, sigmatism is pathological.

*[Lambdacismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambdacismo)* (*lambdacism* in English) is the lateralization of the rhotic sounds, that is, the pronunciation of /r/ as /l/. It can be a dialectal feature or a speech problem. If the latter, it's a subtype of rhotacism.

The specific type of *yeísmo* found in Rioplatense Spanish, where the merger of former /j/ and /ʎ/ (*y* and *ll*) is pronounced as a postalveolar fricative (voiced [ʒ] or voiceless [ʃ]) is called *yeísmo con [rehilamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rehilamiento)*. The term *rehilamiento* seems to be out of fashion in Spanish phonetics now, but it refers to the noticeably fricative character of the sounds, as opposed to the more common realizations, which tend to be approximant.

There are some authors that employ the term *[lleísmo](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Lle%C3%ADsmo)* for the phenomenon of **distinguishing** the phonemes /j/ and /ʎ/. Note that *yeísmo* (non-distinction) is the norm in Spanish as a whole.

There's no specific name, that I know of, for the assibilation of /r/ found in [Andean Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andean_Spanish). This, again, is a feature of the dialect, not a speech defect.

Comment: Is there a recording I could listen to, to get the idea of the assibilation of /r/?

Comment: *Lambdacismo* is common in some regions when the *r* is in coda position. Ozuna, a Portorrican singer, is a good example of the phenomenon. Notice how *decir* and *seguir* are pronounced as *decil* and *seguil* in [Amor genuino](https://youtu.be/jQkJMutvYkA) in the first stanza (around 00:20). The difference is subtle but noticeable.

Comment: @aparente001 My go-to source for assibilated /r/ is Mercedes Sosa. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UnVjNugKws) and listen to how she says "Costa **R**ica" (0:21) and "nuevos a**rr**eglos" (1:49); also [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEwPJbAaEZQ) where she says "Carlos del Co**rr**o ahí en la **r**adio..." (0:48) and then "bo**rr**achos, locos de la gue**rra**" (1:12).