# ¿Qué término describe lo contrario al betacismo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, pronunciación, terminología, betacismo

Hace poco, cuando uno de mis amigos argentinos me dijo que quería ["yesear impunemente"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32550/5481) tuve que revisarme las definiciones de yeísmo y lleísmo (distinción de los fonemas /ʝ/ y /ʎ/, escritos "y" y "ll"). Eso me llevó a preguntarme si había un fenómeno parecido con la be u la uve, y las respuestas a [una pregunta antigua del sitio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12890/5481) me dieron la respuesta.

Si el [betacismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12892/5481) es un fenómeno lingüístico

> que consiste en unir la pronunciación de los sonidos [b] y [β] o [v]

¿tiene un nombre el fenómeno lingüístico en el que se pronuncian de forma diferenciada la be y la uve?  Es decir, ¿qué fenómeno es al betacismo lo que el lleísmo es al yeísmo?

(Por cierto, que en [What other terms are there like yeísmo and betacismo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30722/5481) [pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14627/pablodf76) explica rotacismo, sigmatismo, lambdacismo y rehilamiento.)

Answer (score 1):

Aunque no refiere específicamente a los sonidos [b] y [β] o [v], podría ser que buscas la palabra [alófono o alofonismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al%C3%B3fono).

Segun, la profesora Eva Núñez, en ["A diachronic approach to the confusion of b with v in Spanish"](https://www.academia.edu/35625081/_A_diachronic_approach_to_the_confusion_of_b_with_v_in_Spanish._In_Diachronic_Applications_in_Hispanic_Linguistics_edited_by_E._N%C3%BA%C3%B1ez_126-166._London_Cambridge_Scholars_2016), ella define un alófono de tal manera:

> an audibly distinct variant of a phoneme; e.g. in Spanish the phoneme /b/ has two allophones: a plosive [b] and a fricative [β].

También, encontré una interesante explicación sobre "[Las reglas alofónicas en español](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/allophonr.htm)" que dice:

Alófonos en español:

> ... can be illustrated first of all with the voiced stops [b, d, g] and
>   the voiced fricatives [β, ð, ɣ]. A parallel exists between these two
>   groups of sounds, in that the places of articulation of the stops
>   exactly match those of the fricatives, as shown in Table 1 below.
>   [image: Alófonos]

O podríamos inventar una palabra (después de hablar con la Academia [image: Smileys]por supuesto), por ejemplo como:

> 1. Desbetacismo
> 2. Contrabetacismo
> 3. Alófono b/v
> 4. Bevelófono

No podría encontrar ni en inglés un antónimo específico a esta separación de sonidos, pero alófono alude al fenómeno general.

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene un voto negativo (aparte de ser el único voto del post). Ya que es evidente que algo de trabajo tiene (una presentación más que decente y algo de investigación), si el contenido no convence no estaría de más que quien esté dispuesto a votar negativo (en lugar de simplemente abstenerse de votar positivo) explique un poco sus motivaciones para penalizar esta respuesta y explicar si ese voto negativo podría revertirse sis se corrige algo en la misma. Penalizar si explicar, sobre todo a usuarios en los niveles de experiencia más bajos, es contraproducente para todos. Gracias.

Comment: @Diego ¿Qué opina Ud.?  Si no tiene sentido esto, lo puedo borrar.

Comment: Yo diría que es una respuesta válida decir "no existe un término". Creo que [alófono](https://dle.rae.es/al%C3%B3fono) es un término más amplio que lo que buscamos. Mi comentario más que sobre el contenido de esta respuesta iba sobre penalizar sin intentar aclarar l oque vemos mal de un post. Yo dejaría esta respuesta un tiempo, a ver qué pasa y qué otras cosas aporta la gente. Para borrarla siempre hay tiempo

Comment: @Diego: En referencia a tu primer comentario, ¿habéis llegado a un consenso al respecto en Spanish.SE? (No he encontrado ninguna discusión sobre el tema en Meta). En Italian.SE no del todo: incluso en [este post](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1337) me pidieron que cambiara el título de "Please leave a comment to explain the reason of your downvote" al que hay ahora mismo para que no pareciera que los usuarios que no están de acuerdo no pudieran participar en la discusión.

Comment: Lo pregunto porque en Italian.SE a veces me encuentro con situaciones como esta, pero últimamente, como moderadora, no me atrevo a escribir comentarios como el tuyo (aunque estoy totalmente de acuerdo con lo que has escrito).

Comment: @Charo supongo que esta pregunta es más adecuada en Meta... Pero yo prefiero no "requerir" un comentario para cualquier voto negativo, aunque estoy de acuerdo con escribir comentarios como el de Diego preguntando por la razón en casos como este, en los que claramente la respuesta es de buena calidad, está trabajada y aporta información interesante.

Comment: @Charo aquí no se requiere el comentario cuando dejas el voto negativo (no creo que haya de todas maneras una forma de obligar a hacerlo), pero alguna de las iniciativas que hemos llevado a cabo a lo largo del tiempo queda recogida entre los [comentarios útiles](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2624/5481), que son una lista de plantillas para comentarios que puedes usar en las colas de revisión o donde sea para recordar a los usuarios de las buenas prácticas del stack.

Comment: Interesante, @Diego.